# Reactive Programming in synchronous environment: performance vs dependency management

Tags: performance, reactive-programming, dependency-management, synchronous, rx.net

I understand that Reactive Programming shine in asynchronous environment (web request, or heavy IO/multi-threading/background task. However, in synchronous world, I found that Reactive Programming still give a great benefit of freeing dependency management burden from the programmer. I am writing a desktop app using C# that act like a spreadsheet: lots inputs, calculation on these inputs, and outputs. I am using RX.net and enjoying the benefit free dependency management it gave me: when an input change, i do not need to know what calculation need to be redo, and what ui need to be updated. However, as there are more synchronous/sequential calculation involve, the performance hit from using observable become greater. Consider these 2 ways of coding:

```
  private static void async_world()
  {
     Subject<string> a_ob = new Subject<string>();
     IObservable<string> A_ob = a_ob.Select(str =>
     {
        return my_to_upper(str);
     });
     IObservable<string> AA_ob = A_ob.Select(str => $"{str}{str}");
     IObservable<string> AAA_ob = A_ob.Select(str => $"{str}{str}{str}");
     IObservable<string> AA_AAA_ob = Observable.CombineLatest(AA_ob, AAA_ob,
     (AA, AAA) =>
     {
        return $"{AA}_{AAA}";
     });

     AA_AAA_ob.Subscribe(str => Console.Out.WriteLine(str));
     a_ob.OnNext("a");
  }

  private static void sync_world()
  {
     Subject<string> a_ob = new Subject<string>();

     IObservable<string> result_ob = a_ob.Select(str =>
     {
        var upper = my_to_upper(str);

        var AA = $"{upper}{upper}";
        var AAA = $"{upper}{upper}{upper}";

        return $"{AA}_{AAA}";
     });

     result_ob.Subscribe(str => Console.Out.WriteLine(str));
     a_ob.OnNext("a");
  }
```

assuming my_to_upper() is a slow process:

```
  private static string my_to_upper(string str)
  {
     Console.Out.WriteLine($"{str}.ToUpper...");
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2000; j++)
        {

        }
     }
     Console.Out.WriteLine($"{str}.ToUpper...done");
     return str.ToUpper();
  }
```

for async_world(), my_to_upper() is executed twice comparing to sync_world(). It would be nice that when data arrive ( on each onNext call ) A_ob perform calculation and "cache" the result of my_to_upper() and pass it on to AA_ob and AAA_ob

So my question is: is this a trade off we have to make: let the computer manage dependency automatically for us with inefficient performance, or manually manage dependency to gain better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to 'cache' the result with the various `Publish` over-loads:

Here's a Published form of async with Publish + RefCount:

```
private static void async_world_publish_refcount()
{
    Subject<string> a_ob = new Subject<string>();
    IObservable<string> A_ob = a_ob
        .Select(str => my_to_upper(str)) //same function call as async_world_original, just removed braces.
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();

    IObservable<string> AA_ob = A_ob.Select(str => $"{str}{str}");
    IObservable<string> AAA_ob = A_ob.Select(str => $"{str}{str}{str}");
    IObservable<string> AA_AAA_ob = Observable.CombineLatest(AA_ob, AAA_ob,
    (AA, AAA) =>
    {
        return $"{AA}_{AAA}";
    });

    AA_AAA_ob.Subscribe(str => Console.Out.WriteLine(str));
    a_ob.OnNext("a");
}
```

And here's a Published form without RefCount:

```
private static void async_world_publish_only()
{
    Subject<string> a_ob = new Subject<string>();
    IObservable<string> AA_AAA_ob = a_ob
        .Select(str => my_to_upper(str)) //same function call as async_world_original, just removed braces.
        .Publish(A_ob => 
            Observable.CombineLatest(
                A_ob.Select(str => $"{str}{str}"),
                A_ob.Select(str => $"{str}{str}{str}"),
                (AA, AAA) => $"{AA}_{AAA}"
            )
        );

    AA_AAA_ob.Subscribe(str => Console.Out.WriteLine(str));
    a_ob.OnNext("a");
}
```

The publish without RefCount form is probably preferred if you're a fan of functional, reactive-y things: It effectively caches an observable's result values, and makes them available inside the limited lambda scope where you have to produce a selector to decide what to do with it. You could if necessary nest `Publish` lambdas to access multiple "cached" observable values.

`Publish` + `RefCount`, in contrast promotes statement-y, iterative-looking pipelines. Generally less recommended.

You can read more about `Publish`, `RefCount` and hot vs cold observables [here](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect).

Comment: Thank you! Hot observable is what i need. With hot observable, intermediate observable don't have to re-evaluate.